# Can I ask questions related to card processing?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm developing credit card processing in our Point-of-Sale software, and would like to find a community where I can get some help. Is this the right one? If not, what Stack Exchange community would I need?

For example, a question I might ask would be something like "Is there a difference in processing rates when using an EMV chip card as opposed to swiping?" or "Can I prevent a transaction from completing if the Avs lookup was not successful?"

**EDIT**

Those last two examples are quite vague, but a more realistic question would be "How quickly do debit transactions occur on consumer accounts?"

Comment: Not sure I understand the last question - how quickly in what sense? Is it how quickly they are posted to the account after the actual transaction?

Answer (score 6):

It's not about finance from the perspective of an individual, so I think it's probably off-topic here.

I'm not sure where else you could ask - maybe StackOverflow itself, though there might be a risk that people would consider the questions as only answerable by the relevant vendors/manufacturers.

Thanks for checking first :-)

Comment: Yeah, I came here because I know SO wouldn't appreciate those kinds of questions, and I'm a Delphi developer, and the Delphi community there is very.... well, can't find the word. Strange? Picky? Yeah anyway...

Comment: It actually kinda sucks because the URL is money.stackexchange.com and yet, it's about personal finance.

Comment: Please see my edit in the Q...

Comment: @JerryDodge Some history: [Should we remove the “& Money” part from the site name and logo, to prevent repeated confusion about what is on-topic?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/should-we-remove-the-money-part-from-the-site-name-and-logo-to-prevent-repe)